# letting deferred finish in esri javascript api before proceeding with code - labelPoints

Tags: javascript, deferred, esri

I am having trouble getting my labelPoints done before finishing the rest of my code. I know this is some sort of deferred/callback issue that I am not understanding and have not been able to find many examples of how to do this with the esri javascript api.

Basically I am using centroids where I can to create a click point from an address search, but on odd shaped polygons I need to use labelPoints to ensure the point is actually in the polygon.

The executeQueries() works fine in the if, but in the else it doesn't run correctly as the executeQueries() happens before the labelPoints are retrieved. I tried adding .on("label-points-complete") to fire the executeQueries() but that doesn't appear to be helping. Just trying to get the geometry from the labelPoint before I execute the rest. I have tried this 1000 ways with no success. Thanks for any tips.

```
function symbolizeFoundFeatures(featureSet) {
    //If we get a result set
    if (featureSet.features.length > 0) {
    //Highlight the feature
    var polygonJson = { "rings": featureSet.features[0].geometry.rings, "spatialReference": map.spatialReference };
    var selectedGeometry = featureSet.features[0].geometry;
    searchedGraphic = map.graphics.add(new esri.Graphic(new esri.geometry.Polygon(polygonJson), 
        new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol(
            esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
            new esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol(esri.symbol.SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
            new esri.Color([0, 0, 0, 1]), 1),
            new esri.Color([255, 0, 0, 0.2]))
        ));

    selectedCentroid = searchedGraphic.geometry.getExtent().getCenter();
    var markerSymbol = map.graphics.add(new SimpleMarkerSymbol(SimpleMarkerSymbol.STYLE_SQUARE, 10,
        new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
        new Color([255, 0, 0]), 1),
        new Color([0, 255, 0, 0.25])
    ));
    var searchedGraphicPoint = new Graphic(selectedCentroid, markerSymbol);

//the if here runs everything perfectly
    if (searchedGraphic.geometry.contains(selectedCentroid)) {
        useThisPointToInitiateClick = selectedCentroid;
        executeFromSearchedPoint = "Yes";
        executeQueries();
    }
    else 
      {geometryService.labelPoints([searchedGraphic.geometry], function (labelPoints) {
         console.log("in contains else ");
         var searchedGraphicLabelPoint = new Graphic(labelPoints[0], markerSymbol);
         map.graphics.add(searchedGraphicLabelPoint);
         useThisPointToInitiateClick = labelPoints[0];
         console.log(useThisPointToInitiateClick);
         executeFromSearchedPoint = "Yes";
         console.log("before execute queries, after adding center points");
     });
     }
     }
}

geometryService.on("label-points-complete", function (evt) {
     console.log("hi");
     console.log(executeFromSearchedPoint);
     executeQueries();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply call executeQueries() inside the labelPoints callback?

and remove the `geometryService.on("label-points-complete`

```
else 
      {geometryService.labelPoints([searchedGraphic.geometry], function (labelPoints) {
         console.log("in contains else ");
         var searchedGraphicLabelPoint = new Graphic(labelPoints[0], markerSymbol);
         map.graphics.add(searchedGraphicLabelPoint);
         useThisPointToInitiateClick = labelPoints[0];
         console.log(useThisPointToInitiateClick);
         executeFromSearchedPoint = "Yes";
         console.log("before execute queries, after adding center points");
executeQueries();
     });
     }
```

Comment: I thought I had tried every variation on earth of where and how and what order I could call things, but obviously I missed that one right under my nose. Thanks a million